# SQL to Linq to Entities conversion

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble to convert this SQL to Linq To Entities. Can someone explain me how I should break it down?

```
select
    p.ID, p.Name, p.IsActive, ug.Name 
from 
    Projects as p 
inner join UserGroups as ug ON p.UserGroups_ID = ug.ID
where 
    p.UserGroups_ID IN (select UserGroups_ID from UsersToUserGroups where Users_ID = 1)
    and 
    p.IsDeleted = 0
order by 
    p.UserGroups_ID, 
    p.Name
```

Thanks

Comment: Nobody?
I can provide a screen-shot of the diagram if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(
from p in [context].Projects
join ug in [context].UserGroups
on p.UserGroups_ID equals ug.ID
where ug.Users.Any(x => x.ID.Equals(userId))
&& p.IsDeleted.Equals(false)
orderby p.UserGroups_ID, p.Name
select new
{
     ID = p.ID,
     Name = p.Name,
     IsActiveStatus = p.IsActive,
     GroupName = ug.Name
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from p in context.Projects
              join ug in context.UserGroups
                  on p.UserGroups_ID equals ug.ID
              where (from utug in context.UserToUserGroups
                     where utug.Users_ID == 1
                     select UserGroups_ID).Contains(p.UserGroups_ID)
                  && !p.IsDeleted
              order by p.UserGroups_ID, p.Name
              select new { p.ID, p.Name, p.IsActive, UserGroupName = ug.Name };
```

Comment: I get an error on "ug.Name" in the select saying `anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name`, any idea?

Comment: operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type .. on line `&& !p.IsDeleted`. I tried to modify this but can't get it to work either.
Also, the table `UserToUserGroups` is not there (intelisence) because L2E see it has a relational table between users and groups, I can't use it.